# current_user available when using firefox but not Chrome

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using Rails and Devise in a Rails application.

In my code, I am trying to use current_user in layouts/_header.html.erb.

```
<% Rails.logger.debug("Time is: #{Time.now} - Current User: #{current_user}") %>
```

When I use Firefox on my MAC to run the application, here's what I have in the log file:

```
Time is: 2013-06-18 16:21:42 - Current User: #<User:0x007fae442cf020>
```

When I use Chrome on my MAC to run the application, here's what I have in the log file:

```
Time is: 2013-06-18 16:20:33 - Current User: 
Rendered layouts/_promo_bar.html.erb (3.4ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 657ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass):
  27:   <div class="promo-bar-box last-right-box">
  28:     <div class="request-invitation-text">
  29:       <% Rails.logger.debug("Time is: #{Time.now} - Current User: #{current_user}") %>
  30:       <% reg_user =  user_registered_for_event(current_user.email) %>

app/views/layouts/_promo_bar.html.erb:30:in `_app_views_layouts__promo_bar_html_erb__785786602602486184_70193263335300'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: did you actually login to the app using Chrome? current_user is going to be nil until you do - use `user_signed_in?` to check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are accessing a page without having logged in yet. If the session isn't set then current_user isn't going to exist and throw an error when trying to access one of its attributes, in this case being the user's email.

If you are logged in, try clearing your session cookie via Devloper Tools (hamburger icon > tools > Developer Tools). And reloading the page.

Comment: I had some code to check if the user is logged in, before using current_user. I accidentally deleted it and did not notice. Your answer gave me the hint I needed to fix the problem, and I was able to get the previous version from my GitHub repo.